# run ruby file in model or controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have the following file which I create a dynamic CSS menus with all my existing. but this only runs when rebooting the server. How could run it on my model or my controller?

menu-icon.scss.erb

```
li [class^="icon-menu"], li [class*=" icon-menu"] {
  background-position: left center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 16px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 22px;
}

<% Menu.all.each do |m| %>
  .icon-menu<%= m.id %> {
    background-image: url('/icons/<%= m.icon_file_name %>');
  }
<% end %>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "run it on model or controller"? This is scss.erb  file, that's not *runnable*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you want to do is generate some dynamic CSS, why not just use a plain vanilla `erb` partial and then [`content_for`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-the-content_for-method) like

```
<% content_for :menu do %>
  <% Menu.all.each do |m| %>
    .icon-menu<%= m.id %> {
      background-image: url('/icons/<%= m.icon_file_name %>');
    }
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Then whenever you want to display the menu, use `yield` to render it.

But this feels like a "wrong" solution to the problem either way...